# How do I make a correct request using Zend_Soap_Client?

Tags: php, zend-framework, soap

I am making a soap request with the following code:

```
$client = new Zend_Soap_Client($ws_url);

$reqFilter = array();
$reqFilter['CustomTemplateId'] = 33117; 
$reqFilter['StartDate'] = '2011-11-01T00:00:00';
$reqFilter['EndDate'] = '2011-11-01T00:00:00';

$secArr = Array();
$secArr['Key'] = '----------';
$secArr['UserName'] = 'joe';
$secArr['Password'] = '----------';

try{
  $result = $client->RequestCustomReport(array('reportDefinition'=>$reqFilter),array('securityCredentials'=>$secArr) );
}
catch(Exception $e){
  echo 'bad times';
  echo $client->getLastRequest().'<hr>';
  echo $e;
}
```

It generates this actual soap request:

```
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:ns1="http://api.dc-storm.com/broker/engage/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <env:Body>
        <ns1:RequestCustomReport>
            <ns1:reportDefinition>
                <ns1:CustomTemplateId>33117</ns1:CustomTemplateId>
                <ns1:StartDate>2011-11-01T00:00:00</ns1:StartDate>
                <ns1:EndDate>2011-11-01T00:00:00</ns1:EndDate>
            </ns1:reportDefinition>
        <param1>
            <item>
                <key>securityCredentials</key>
                <value>
                    <item>
                        <key>Key</key>
                        <value>--------------</value>
                    </item>
                    <item>
                        <key>UserName</key>
                        <value>joe</value>
                    </item>
                    <item>
                        <key>Password</key>
                        <value>-------------</value>
                    </item>
                </value>
            </item>
        </param1>               
        </ns1:RequestCustomReport>
    </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

Comparing this to what should be requested:

```
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:ns1="http://api.dc-storm.com/broker/engage/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <env:Body>
        <ns1:RequestCustomReport>
            <ns1:reportDefinition>
                <ns1:CustomTemplateId>33117</ns1:CustomTemplateId>
                <ns1:StartDate>2011-11-01T00:00:00</ns1:StartDate>
                <ns1:EndDate>2011-11-01T00:00:00</ns1:EndDate>
            </ns1:reportDefinition>
            <ns1:securityCredentials>
                <ns1:Key>--------------------</ns1:Key>
                <ns1:UserName>joe</ns1:UserName>
                <ns1:Password>--------------------</ns1:Password>
            </ns1:securityCredentials>
        </ns1:RequestCustomReport>
        </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

The issue is the "securityCredentials" node which is formatted incorrectly. What I dont understand is how the fact "reportDefinition" is correct but why not the "securityCredentials". I'm passing the parameters "securityCredentials" and "reportDefinition" the same way into the soap method and would expect the structure to be created from parsing the wsdl.

I've checked the wsdl and the definition for securityCredentials is present and is linked in the method parameter the same way as reportDefinition.

Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

Without the WSDL, I am guessing everyone will be guessing on your problem. So here is my guess.

Try this:

```
$client->RequestCustomReport(array(
    'reportDefinition'    => $reqFilter, 
    'securityCredentials' => $secArr
));
```